# CloudFormation Invalid / Unsupported DB Parameter: rds.logical_replication

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

While defining parameter group for an RDS cluster in CloudFormation like this:

```
"TestDBParameterGroup": {
      "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBParameterGroup",
      "Properties": {
        "Description": "my parameter group with logical replication on",
        "Family": "aurora-postgresql11",
        "Parameters": {
          "rds.logical_replication": true
        },
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "hiya:billto:costcenter",
            "Value": "my-costcenter"
          },
          {
            "Key": "hiya:billto:product",
            "Value": "my-product"
          },
          {
            "Key": "hiya:billto:owner",
            "Value": "my-team"
          },
          {
            "Key": "hiya:operations:contact",
            "Value": "my-team"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
...
```

I get this error: `Invalid / Unsupported DB Parameter: rds.logical_replication`

When I list parameter groups on the console, this parameter exists. I have used it manually with RDS instances created by hand. I don't know why won't it recognize in CF. I've tried with both values `true` and `1`.

Anyone knows if there's a problem with underscores or dots?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using [AWS::RDS::DBClusterParameterGroup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-dbclusterparametergroup.html) not `AWS::RDS::DBParameterGroup`.

`rds.logical_replication` is cluster level setting, not db instance setting.